# Choosing between JSON file and csv file to read data from in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I am working on a script in Python where I need to read a number of IP addresses classified in different sheets in excel file and I also have the option of doing the same form JSON file.

May I have suggestion on reading from what type of file will be faster? JSON or csv file in terms of performance?

Comment: my guess is not much difference, may be csv is faster , timeit and help us know.

Comment: For 2D/tabular data (i.e. no multi-level structures) CSV is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know using pandas module will be an overkill for what you are trying to accomplish.

you can try
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

For easy tasks like this, using tabular simple data csv is quick and easy with a low footprint, for more complex entities json is better option.